# What film has The Rock investigating murders on Mars (and was there a sequel?)

Tags: story-identification, movie

This movie is set in the future, with a lot of sci-fi elements. If I'm not mistaken, the plot consists of mysterious murders on a lunar/Martian base (not sure which) which is used for scientific experiments.

A squad is sent from Earth to investigate. The squad leader is portrayed by The Rock (Dwayne Johnson). During the course of the movie

> several squad members die, until just two are alive (the leader and the “hero”). In the end “The Rock” transforms into a creature just like the ones that have been terrorizing the base. He is then killed by the “hero”.

Throughout the movie there are many scenes that make the movie feel like a first person shooter.

Does anyone know the name of this film and if it has any sequels?

Comment: So you should have looked up "[first person shooter](http://www.imdb.com/keyword/first-person-shooter/)" rather than "Dwayne Johnson" on IMDB

Comment: Wait. You actually watched this movie? I didn't realize anyone had.

Comment: It was on TV. I didn't have anything to do.

Comment: I actually love this film! It's so awful but at the same time solid plot and awesome action. The one quote that gets me is how the humanoid martians had `an extra chomrosome` making them `super human`... Yep, pretty sure an extra chromosome gives you down syndrome...

Comment: @Starkers - they are many types of [trisomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisomy) - only one of which is Down syndrome

Comment: @HorusKol, yes, you are correct, It's called trisomy XXI (or 21) because it's exactly a mutation on the 21st chromosome :)

Comment: Doom is separate movie. If you mistakenly found sequels, it was for Dhoom series (India).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the big screen adaptation of [Doom](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0419706/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). And no, there are no sequels.

BTW, you could've easily solved this yourself if you searched IMDB.com for all the movies that [Dwayne Johnson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0425005/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t10) acted in.

Comment: While the OP could have gone to IMDB and clicked each link in Dwayne Johnson's filmogragy (all 82 credits), that doesn't mean that *they* could have easily answered their own question. I know I've searched for some things before that I saw the answer but didn't believe it was right because I miss-remembered some details.

Comment: Can you find any video not regarding Wrestling/Comedy?
http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0425005/videogallery?ref_=nm_phs_vi, btw, thankyou @System Down

Comment: @Oak: counter-question: can you smell what The Rock is cooking?

Comment: @Oak - Looking at the videos is the wrong approach. It takes way too long. Just look at the titles and look at the posters and read the synopsis. You can also cut down the number of titles you look at if you know the time period. So for instance you saw it in 2007, then start looking at movies in 2007 and go back in time.

Comment: @Xantec - 82 credits *not* filtered by time and other hints.

Comment: And, just because I've seen it referenced before, there exist Indian action movies named *Dhoom* and *Dhoom 2* (as well as *Dhoom 3*) which are completely unrelated.

Comment: You should actually watch Dhoom 3... It defies every logic possible in any sci-fi or real world.

Answer (score 5):

The best option might be to [look him up on IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0425005/#actor), but not in this case, as the list is quite big.
Luckily, a simple [Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=sci+fi+movie+with+dwayne+johnson) for "scifi movie with Dwayne Johnson" suffices here.
The first two results are of a film called "[*Doom*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0419706/)".
On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_%28film%29) it says:

> In an interview with executive producer John Wells, he stated that a second film would be put into production if the first was a success at the box office. Ticket sales for the opening weekend totaled more than US$15.3 million, but promptly dropped to $4.2 million in its second weekend.

So, no, there's no sequel...